# ocaml lcs without objects like Array

Tags: arrays, ocaml, fold, lcs

How can I find the longest common subsequence without using Arrays and only List folds in ocaml

Comment: implement arrays using list folds!

Comment: i'm restricted to functional data structures only

Comment: please define _least common subsequence_ or provide a link.

Comment: crap i meant longest common subsequence (editted)

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic example of [Dynamic
programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming): the
function to implement can be easily specified recursively, but the
subproblems corresponding to the recursive calls have a lot of
overlaps. A naive recursive implementation will do useless work by
recomputing these subproblems, leading to an exponential running time,
while either memoization or different approach lead to a polynomial
algorithm.

The formulation of the Longuest Common Subsequence (LCS) problem given
[on
Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem)
is the following (pseudocode):

```
LCS(X,Y,0,0) = []
LCS(X,Y,i,j) =
  if X[i] = Y[j] then X[i]::LCS(X,Y,i-1,j-1)
  else longest(LCS(X,Y,i-1,j), LCS(X,Y,i,j-1))
```

When transformed to take lists rather than arrays and indices as
parameters, you have the following formulation (still pseudocode):

```
LCS([], []) = []
LCS([x],[]) = []
LCS([], [y]) = []
LCS(x::xs, y::ys) =
  if x = y then x::LCS(xs, ys)
  else longest(LCS(x::xs, ys), LCS(xs, y::ys))
```

It should be easy to get an OCaml implementation out of this (I assume
this is an exercise and will let you come with the solution by
yourself), but this will be an exponential algorithm with a `O(2^N)`
worst-case running time on inputs of length `N`.

To see where the inefficiency comes from on an example, assume the
input is `[x;y;z]` and `[x';y';z']` with `x` different from `x'`. `lcs
[x;y;z] [x';y';z']` will make two recursive calls, one `lcs [y;z]
[x';y';z']` and one `lcs [x;y;z] [y';z']`. But then those two calls
will each make two calls, `lcs [z] [x';y';z']` and `lcs [y;z] [y';z']`
for the first one, and `lcs [y;z] [y';z']` and `lcs [x;y;z] [z']` for
the second one. Notice that they both make a recursive call `lcs [y;z]
[y';z']`, which will therefore be computed twice. For a long enough input other subcalls make be recomputed an arbitrarily high number of time.

The solution to avoid this inefficiency is to build a datastructure
that computes each result only once. The traditional way to do this is
to use a mutable 2D matrix to store the results, but you are not
allowed to use that. You may use a functional data structure to store
the results, by computing a list of lists that would correspond to

```
[
  [lcs [x;y;z] [x';y';z']; lcs [x;y;z] [y';z']; lcs [x;y;z] [z']; lcs [x;y;z] [];]; 
  [lcs [y;z] [x';y';z'];   lcs [y;z] [y';z'];   lcs [y;z] [z'];   lcs [y;z] [];];
  [lcs [z] [x';y';z'];     lcs [z] [y';z'];     lcs [z] [z'];     lcs [z] [];];
  [lcs [] [x';y';z'];      lcs [] [y';z'];      lcs [] [z'];      lcs [] [];];
]
```

Finding a simple recursive way to compute this list of results seems
an interesting advanced exercise. For example, you can compute this "square" of side 4 recursively, by computing the bottom-right subsquare of side 3, then folding over it (as a list of list) to compute the left side of the result square, then folding over its row (the head of the list of list) to compute the top side of the result square. More generally, you can define a function `lcs_results xs ys` that takes two sequences of length `M` and `N` and returns the `MxN` list-of-list corresponding to all the subresults that would be computed by `lcs xs ys`, organized in this way.

I assume, however, that you are simply looking for the naive, exponential formulation (again, looks like a teaching
exercise).